# 100% height responsive sidebar

Tags: css, height

How do i go about setting up a full height side bar using a responsive grid system, that is similar to bootstrap?

The issues I am running it to is the `.main` wrapper div collapses to the height of the `.primarycol` div.

I 'm using pull and push classes to adjust the visual layout so the `.secondarycol` div looks like its on the left hand side, even though it is after the `.primarycol` div in the code.

[image: Adding the secondarycol class]

```
<div id="main" class="main content">
<div class="row">
<div id="primarycolumn" class="primarycol col12 col9-768 col3-768-push" role="main"></div>
<div id="secondary" class="secondarycol col12 col3-768 col9-768-pull col7-1024-pull" role="complementary"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Normally the without the .secondarycol` class, the div would and look like this.

[image]

I have tried adding `min-height:100%` to the `.main` div and `height:100%` to the `body` tag, but that makes the `main` div height only ever be the height of the browser window and not the content.

Any suggestions on how I can remedy this would be really welcome.

This is the codepen of my base structure.
http://codepen.io/onebitrocket/pen/ZYQLMm/

I've added in the third column as well as some pages require one.

The column system is based on bootstraps, but i think it's an improved version:
The column classes are declared from smallest size to largest size.
I've also changed the class names to indicate the breakpoint size rather then xs,sm,md,lr etc..

Thanks

Comment: Can you please put the code in a jsfiddle or codepin. You'll probably get an answer quickly if you do.

Comment: Show css code of .secondarycol.

Comment: If I had to guess the push and pull is doing something with floats. You may need to do a clearfix on .secondarycol

Comment: as long as you put 100% height on the sidebar, it will stretch to the height of it's container. I think you just need to go through all of the containers and set proper heights. I mean, if your content is less than the browser height you probably don't want the divs collapsing to be like the screenshot above, right?

Comment: @ShanRobertson Your right for the effect he wants on a tall enough screen. 100% is max(view-height, calculated-height). If the column isn't clearfixed so the right height can be calculated, then he will have the same issue when he scrolls. see http://jsfiddle.net/27kze60s/1/

Comment: Here is a link to my codepen http://codepen.io/onebitrocket/pen/ZYQLMm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, thanks to everyone for the suggestions

I've added the following to the css
`height:100%` to `body`
`min-height:100%` to `.main` 
`overflow:-y`: auto to `.secondarycol`

I've updated the codepen - http://codepen.io/onebitrocket/pen/ZYQLMm/

Answer (score 0):

At least on chrome you need to set the height on the html tag too. Try it - http://jsfiddle.net/27kze60s/

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```